# Don't show submenu

Tags: theming, 8

The following code is for menu--main.html.twig; the submenu is not printed in Drupal 8.

```
{# All menu and submenu items #}

{% for item in items %}
{# Menu with submenu #}
{% if item.below %}
{{ item.title }}
{# Menu -> Submenu #}
{% for item in item.below %}
{% include "@nature/snippet/menu-infinite-child.html.twig" with { 'item': item } %} 
{% endfor %}
{# Menu without submenu #}
{% else %}
{# Menu - Link #}
{% if item.title == 'Home' %}
{{ item.title }} 
{% endif %}
{% if item.title == 'About' %}
{{ item.title }}
{% endif %}
{% if item.title == 'Pages' %}
{{ item.title }}
{% endif %}
{% if item.title == 'Blogs' %}
{{ item.title }}
{% endif %}
{% if item.title == 'Parfolio' %}
{{ item.title }}
{% endif %} 
{% if item.title == 'Contact' %}
{{ item.title }}
{% endif %} {% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: why you create submenu by custom??

Comment: because  it has custom bootstrap style that's why i am choosing this way if you have any idea kindly suggest to me

Comment: in drupal have different module to creating submenu if want to add bootstrap class using menu  arg module

Comment: As with Drupal 7 you have to set the "expanded" flag on each menu item that is a parent. Otherwise the child items will be visible only on the parent's page.

Comment: it's working properly in drupal 7 but i want be in drupal 8

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like a recursive function; it follows the menu tree by invoking itself or a separate twig.

Did you copy the code and put it into menu--main.html.twig? Then you have to change the include statement with the correct path to invoke the correct twig.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the children links from being printed, you have to remove:

```
{# Menu -> Submenu #}
{% for item in item.below %}
  {% include "@nature/snippet/menu-infinite-child.html.twig" with { 'item': item } %} 
{% endfor %}
```